Drawbacks of custom save method to avoid user getting a userprofile_id with a specific value. (Django/Heroku)
In my Django project, I need to avoid users creating a userprofile_id with a value of 3 (3, 13, 203...).
This is an interim workaround another issue which will probably take longer to resolve.
I posted the code below.
But my question relates more to the drawbacks of this interim fix.
What sort of problem could this generate. This is the list I came up with and my answers to each of them:

User_id will be different than userprofile_id - cant see any problems here.
Affect to database integrity when custom method is removed - I cannot see how the remove of the method would affect the database. Hopefully I am right.;
Some performance issue - The save is at the database level which might cause some delays I suppose. This is for a pilot+. I dont expect 1000s of new users a day. Could two users who signup at the same time end up with the same userprofile_id? Would there be a way to limit potential of deadlocks?

the code for those who are curious:
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            # Logic for generating userprofile_id without '3'
            last_userprofile = UserProfile.objects.all().order_by('-id').first()
            print(f'last_userprofile: {last_userprofile.id}')
            if last_userprofile:
                last_id = last_userprofile.id
                print(f'last_id: {last_id}')
                next_id = last_id + 1
                print(f'next_id: {next_id}')
                while '3' in str(next_id):
                    next_id += 1
                self.id = next_id
            else:
                self.id = 1 


Can you explain what the problem is with pk=3?

The main drawback: Django does not always calls .save(..).

The problem with pk=3 is not related to django. Its in relation to an extra device that we use to read userprofile_id through a qr code. Somehow "3" (3, 13, 30... Will render '', '1' and '0')are not picked up. So in order to not stop operations and to allow us time to understand the root cause we came up with this intérim solution.

In what circumstances does Django not always use .save()? (Thanks for raising the point!)

.bulk_create(..), .update(..). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create mostly doing things in bulk.

What database do you use? Normally Django does not decide the primary key, but the database, for PostgreSQL and some others, you can generate a sequence to handle this.

We are using PostGres through Heroku. Following your message, I checked our use of bulk_create() and the update(). We dont use bulk_create(). We do use update, when user when to update their UserProfile, but there userprofile_id wil also remain the same to should be outside the remit. I like your suggestion about sequences.

not using .bulk_create(..) yourself is not (per se) enough, since there can be all sorts of logic that uses the QuerySet, for example django-import-export. So even if no bulk inserts are done explicitly, I think it is dangerous to think that these can not happen.

Your solution has a big problem with concurrency. What Django basically does when save on an object with an id is called is: Try to update row in database if that fails insert a new object. So what can end up happening is that you can end up having two users mapped to the same user profile due to race conditions.

With your solution it is possible for multiple users to end up having the same profile when you create users concurrently.
This happens because of how the save method decides whether to make an update or an insert query. From the documentation the following is what Django does:


If the object’s primary key attribute is set to a value that evaluates to True (i.e., a value other than None or the empty string),
Django executes an UPDATE.
If the object’s primary key attribute is not set or if the UPDATE didn’t update anything (e.g. if primary key is set to a value that
doesn’t exist in the database), Django executes an INSERT.


Given you've set the primary key yourself it is possible that:

Request 1 to create user profile for a user starts.
Request 2 to create user profile for another user starts.
Both get the same calculated id.
One of them finishes the insert first.
The other ends up updating the newly inserted row.

This results in two users having the same profile. You can work around this problem by forcing Django to perform an insert by setting the force_insert keyword argument to True:
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        # Logic for generating userprofile_id without '3'
        last_userprofile = UserProfile.objects.all().order_by('-id').first()
        print(f'last_userprofile: {last_userprofile.id}')
        if last_userprofile:
            last_id = last_userprofile.id
            print(f'last_id: {last_id}')
            next_id = last_id + 1
            print(f'next_id: {next_id}')
            while '3' in str(next_id):
                next_id += 1
            self.id = next_id
        else:
            self.id = 1
        # Force the save to be an insert, an error is better than two users having same profile
        kwargs["force_insert"] = True

This will result in one of the saves erroring out but that's better than two users having the same profile. If needed you can gracefully handle this by catching the exception and handling it.
Another option is to actually solve this by correctly utilizing the database and using transactions. Django's default behaviour is to autocommit each query. You can instead either explicitly create a transaction by using transaction.atomic or tie each HTTP request to a transaction by setting ATOMIC_REQUESTS to True. Along with this to ensure that appropriate locks are created in the database use select_for_update on your query to get the last UserProfile object:
UserProfile.objects.select_for_update().order_by('-id').first()


Note: I don't recommend doing what you are doing, it is best to leave the primary generation up to the database. Treat this only as an interim workaround like you have mentioned and remove it as soon as possible.
Note: Once you work on removing this workaround the sequence generating the IDs would end up producing invalid IDs. Check this question out to solve that problem.

I initially only saw your comment, and found out about your solution just now. Follwoing your comment I did a bit of research. It looks like I could use the @transaction.atomic decorator which could ensure the entire save() operation would be saved as a single unit. Both are a bit of unknown territory to me. Would you have an opinion/experience on using the decorator instead of force_insert? documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/transactions/

@PhilM Yes @transaction.atomic can work, you probably would need to use select_for_update along with it. Also put the decorator around either your view or use it as context manager.

Thanks! I reworked the code based on your suggestion and posted the new version on the original post (@transaction.atomic + select_for_update).

@PhilM feel free to post that as an answer, answers should not be added to the question. Otherwise I'll edit my answer later when I have some time.

Really no exception handling in a problem like this? You do not need be "forcing" any inserts. Both bullets are null points because your code just works wrong. You really think it's a good idea to call all objects in a list rather than searching for one and doing exception handling with save? This code is slow. We do not create users by ordering every ID in the database. Obviously this can't work for websites at scale.

The bullets from the documentation don't matter in this context. "If the object’s primary key attribute is set to a value that evaluates to True", then you are never supposed to run save in the first place.

"If the object’s primary key attribute is not set or if the UPDATE didn’t update anything, Django inserts." Again, you were supposed to check this before inserting or saving. If save fails, I'm still not seeing any evidence that it's going to forcefully insert itself like you are saying. Because that doesn't make any sense. It just doesn't. You handle the exception if it happens and redirect.

You don't just let save check the primary key for you, you have to actually check if that primary key already exists yourself. Everytime you create a user, you start by checking yourself to see if it exists already using Model.objects.get(pk=id). Most of the time the code will fail to find the user you are looking for, then you know that that error means you are ready to create a new user and you can do that in the except block. If it finds the user, it's already created. Do nothing. Skip the except block.

@AbdulAzizBarkat feel free to post the answer. You deserve the credits :)

@PhilM I've edited the answer with an additional note at the bottom (You'll face that problem once you remove this workaround).

@AbdulAzizBarkat This user started a discussion chat with me and repeatedly told me I was wrong about his code before silently changing the line days later. PhilM, Just because someone is giving you the code you want to paste into your program does not mean that they "deserve the credits". You have to think logically about this. The code before I told him it would not work would call all objects in the database and order all of them before finding the first object. This would not work for a site with more than 100 users and is not acceptable an answer. Please review the other issues I noted.

Answer 1
Differing user IDs and user profile IDs shouldn't matter as long as you keep track of them. In fact, I kind of like this idea of using a different user ID on the backend, one that simply represents a number, rather than the user ID the user created. I do this on my websites so as to use cookies that protect my user's privacy. I refer only to them by their number, never the name they gave me.
Answer 2
I cant see any forthcoming issues with the database but remember, part of the advantage of Django is that we can generate a SQL database using models. We may need to edit our database in production to increase functionality or scope, but in development, I recommend making sure that Django is generating the SQL table correctly before any attempt to use it. So maybe make sure that your SQL database is being generated correctly from a new database when calling migrate.
Answer 3
Well, strictly speaking, a Python program compiled using CPython, effectively running as C machine code, will not reach deadlock on the processor. Fundamentally, those problems are solved at much lower level using pipelining and parallelism.
You could have two users submit the same user ID at the same time, one will be created first, and the other will hit an error. Handle that error within an try/except block and use a HTTPResponseRedirect to direct the user back to a page that tells them to try again with a different user ID.

Your point 3 is wrong, potentially because you don't understand how save works. When Django sees an object with an id / pk it tries to run an update query on the database if that fails then it tries to insert a new object. In this case it is very possible two objects get the same id, one gets saved to the database and the other immediately updates that object.

When Django sees? Who is Django? We use Django functions to look up the object on the MySQL database. We never call save if the object is already written. You need to query that yourself. If you took a course in Computer Architecture then you would know that one of these processes must finish first. Even if this happens in between looking up the object and running save, the save function will fail. That is what we want. That tells us the user is already created. You can use a try/except block to handle this easily. Not sure where you heard that Django can't scale and handle multiple users.

That's a very naive outlook for how a web application works. In a production deployment it is very likely to have multiple instances of the application running at the same time. Unless you've set up transactions properly what I talk about in my comment is very much possible. "If you took a course in Computer Architecture then you would know that" that's an unnecessarily defensive statement let's not assume things and make statements like that. It very much risks spilling over into breaking the code of conduct

I'm not really sure you understand how MySQL databases work. This would be a problem for all websites that use MySQL. There is only one instance of the application running on the server, handling multiple requests. So you are fundamentally flawed here. You need to use errors to guide your code. If save fails it does not just malform the table and insert it anyway. Youre going to have to provide some sources for that if you think that's how Django works. When save fails, you handle it in a try/except block. It's not hard.

The database obviously is not the only part of your application your server is interacting with it. There might be multiple instances of your application behind a load balancer / reverse proxy. Combine this with how save works (described in my answer here with documentation links) and you'll see how it is possible for race conditions to happen here.

Everything from the documentation you quoted does not matter because you are supposed to check those conditions yourself before saving to the table.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
